# URL Rewriting help using IIS Rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Please help me redirecting my URL using IIS rewrite the following:

`https://domain.com:8080/Context/services/.*`

to

`https://domain.com:8443/Context/services/.*`

We only have 8080 port open and that's why need redirection for SSL.

But at the same time I don't want any other URLs getting redirected such as 
https://domain.com:8080/Context/xyz (or anything except services)/.*

I tried the following but it is not working:

```
<rule name="HTTPS Request on 8080 Redirect to HTTPS Request on 8443 for Root" 
      patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="https(.*)Context/services/.*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="8080" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}:8443/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<rule name="HTTPS Request on 8080 Redirect to HTTPS Request on 8443 for Root" 
     patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(Context/services/.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="8080" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}:8443/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

If you review the [Accessing URL Parts section here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Accessing_URL_Parts_from_a_Rewrite_Rule), you will notice that the match URL contains everything after the root of the directory it is placed in. For something in the root directory as is your case, it will be everything after the hostname and port without a leading slash /.

Comment: I tried the above rewrite rule as well but it is not redirecting the URL.

Comment: @user1667538 What does happen? Also, where is this rewrite rule placed? This is assuming this rule is in the root directory. I haven't used patternSyntax="ECMAScript" in the past so you could try removing that as well.